# Web3 how to listen to contract events on pending transactions?

Tags: web3js

I'm currently trying to listen to contract events from a contract address but on pending transactions.
But I only got confirmed transaction on the instead of pending.
Here my code

```js
let subscription = web3.eth.subscribe("logs", {
  fromBlock: "pending",
  address: ["0x0eD7e52944161450477ee417DE9Cd3a859b14fD0"],
  topics: [], 
});

subscription.on("data", async (event) => {
  const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(event.transactionHash);
  console.log("tx", tx); //this is confirmed transaction because it has block number in it
});
```

How to listen events only for pending transactions ?

Comment: event logs are fired and saved after transactions are mined and successful. pending transactions can't emit events.

Answer (score 2):

subscribe for events for pending transactions not possible.
event executed only when call function in smartcontract.
so, if transaction have status pending - any events not executed.